# Error: 'device not Configured' when Sending Email in .NetCoreApp V1.0 using Mailkit

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, mailkit

I'm currently developing an Asp .Net Core Application using VS Code on my MAC. I researched on how to send an email since System.Net.Mail is not fully supported,
I came across Mailkit. I added the following dependencies to my JSON file: MailKit V1.6.0 and MimeKit V1.6.0.

but i get an error on:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2 (@"C:\path\to\certificate.p12", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential (new ServiceAccountCredential
    .Initializer ("your-developer-id@developer.gserviceaccount.com") {
    Scopes = new[] { "https://mail.google.com/" },
    User = "username@gmail.com"
}.FromCertificate (certificate));

 using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
   client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587); // Error occurs here.
   client.Authenticate ("mymail@gmail.com", credential.Token.AccessToken);
   client.Send(message);
   client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

I searched for a solution for this online but i couldn't find anything.
Has anyone ever come across this error before and if so, how did you manage to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the exact error message? where is your SMTP configuration?  You cannot simply send an email through google's SMTP without providing credentials

Comment: The exact error message is "device not configured". i just updated my question with my full code. i'm also making use of oauth with my gmail account.

Comment: What's the Exception.StackTrace ?

Comment: MailKit doesn't throw an exception that says "device not configured" - maybe try creating a simple app that connects to something using a TcpClient and seeing if that works?

Comment: @jstedfast The exception in the StackTrace is: [ExtendedSocketException]: {System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException: Device Not Configured at System.Net.Dns.HostResolutionEndHelper(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.Dns.EndGetHostAddresses(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.Dns.<>c.<GetHostAddressesAsync>b__14_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) End of stack trace from previous location

Comment: Looks like a bug in .NET Core or else some sort of misconfiguration of your Mac.

Comment: @jstedfast I tried a simple TCP Client connection and that works fine.

Comment: The stack trace shows it's erroring in System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddressesAsync() - try that with whatever host name you are using. I bet that gives you the same error.

Comment: I wrote the following code System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddressesAsync("smtp.google.com"); which returns an object that has a task status of "waiting for activation" so that code works... I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System.Net;

namespace TestCase {
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            Dns.GetHostAddressesAsync ("smtp.gmail.com").GetAwaiter ().GetResult ();
        }
    }
}
```

I guarantee that fails with the exact same error.

Comment: Yip! I get the same error on that code. Is this a bug? Or is there a solution?

Comment: I would recommend asking the .NET Core developers - maybe it's a bug or maybe they can help you configure whatever device you need to configure. I suspect it's a bug, though.

Comment: I'll post a resolution if the .NET Core developers can assist. Thank you.